# How to fill a region in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I did the following drawing in Tikz:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz] {standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (-0.25,0) circle (2);
        \draw[thick] (0.25,0) circle (2);
        \draw (0.25,0) node[above] {$w$};
        \draw (-0.25,0) node[above] {$z$};
        \draw (0.25,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (-0.25,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (2,0) node {$B$};
        \draw (-2,0) node {$A$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to fill the A and B regions with a light gray. I know how to fill a whole circle but I don't know how to fill such a specific region. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @current_user's response, we can use the `even odd rule` here to color the part that is **inside** a path.

The path traced here is the succession of the two center circles `z` and `w`:

```
\filldraw[thick,fill=green!50,even odd rule] (-0.25,0) circle (2) (0.25,0) circle (2);
```

To explain this rule, I added two arrows, one of origin `z` and end `z'`, the other being `Bb'`.
 These arrows indicate whether their origin `z` and `B` are **inside** or **outside** the path traced. They are always traced to infinity.

Starting from the `z` point, the arrow meets the path twice, two times is **even**, so the `z` point is **outside** the path and therefore the area in which it is located is not colored.

Starting from point `B`, the arrow meets the path once, one is **odd**, so `B` is **inside** the path and is therefore colored.

[image: even-odd-rule]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz] {standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[thick,fill=green!50,even odd rule] (-0.25,0) circle (2) (0.25,0) circle (2);
        \draw (0.25,0) node[above] {$w$};
        \draw (-0.25,0) coordinate (z) node[above] {$z$};
        \draw (0.25,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (-0.25,0) node {$\bullet$};
        \draw (2,0) node {$B$};
        \draw (-2,0) node {$A$};
        %drawing arrows to explain the even odd rule
        \coordinate(z') at (-2.5,.5);
        \draw[->](z)--(z')node[left]{z'};
        \coordinate (b) at (2,.25);
        \coordinate (b') at (2.5,1);
        \draw[->](b)node{$\bullet$}--(b')node[above right]{b'};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzstyle{io} = [fill=black,inner sep=2pt,circle]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (.5,0) circle(2);
                \fill[gray!20] (.25,-5) rectangle (-5,5);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(2);
                \fill[gray!20] (.25,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \end{scope}
        \draw (0,0) circle(2);
        \draw (.5,0) circle(2);
            \node[right] at (-2,0) {$A$};
            \node[left] at (2.5,0) {$B$};
        \node[io,label={$z$}] at (0,0) {};
        \node[io,label={$w$}] at (.5,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Herbert: Thank you! That bug is really awkward …

Comment: I did not undestand how you did the second drawing