# How to paint the regions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanto to paint the figure

[image]

But, I can only do the drawing without the painting.

My codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

        \draw (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);

        \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

        \clip  (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

            \draw (1,1) circle (1);

            \draw (1,-1) circle (1);

            \draw (-1,-1) circle (1);

            \draw (-1,1) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See is this helps. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450289/how-to-fill-a-region-in-tikz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be a way to do it, if you don't mind the center area filled with white color. Draw each arcs individually, and clipped with the small square then filled inside with white color:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw [fill=red] (0,1) arc (180:270:1) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1);
        \draw [fill=blue] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
        {\clip (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
        \draw [fill=white] (0,1) arc (180:270:1) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep center's color (or transparency), you can draw the figure using `even odd rule`. You have to repeat the command, first to fill everything outside central rectangle and a second one to fill with another color inner rectangle corners, with a `clip` path help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
        
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[fill=green!10] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[fill=green!10] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        
    \filldraw [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5) 
    (0,1) arc (180:270:1) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[fill=green!10] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        
    \filldraw [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5) 
    (0,1) arc (180:270:1) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1);

    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
        \filldraw [fill=blue, even odd rule] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5) 
        (0,1) arc (180:270:1) arc (90:180:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]